# Тире перед фразой «само очарование»

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Скажите, нужно ли тире в данном предложении?

*"Испанец (?) само очарование".*

Спасибо!

Comment: можно поставить, если хотите кого-то охарактеризовать, выразить своё впечатление: испанец - само очарование! Но можно и не ставить, если это сарказм, или просто констатация очевидного: испанец само очарование, но...

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: А если так: "Испанец (?) само очарование, он мне понравился сразу".  Здесь нет НО, и вроде бы оба варианта подходят...

Comment: @Sharon Вы, как всегда, правы, я не мастер составления двусмысленных фраз)

Comment: @Буратино  Зря вы не продолжили свою мысль, а были на верном пути. Просто надо было обобщить ваш частный вариант с союзом НО. Вся двусмысленность в том, что в сложном предложении смещаются ударения и тире/паузу уже не всегда можно поставить. То есть продолжение темы может быть любым., а вы предложили конкретное. Я хотела вам просто намекнуть на это...

Comment: @Sharon  Вот в этом и вся загвоздка. Зачем додумывать за автора, переделывать, добавлять (вы, по-моему, не сторонник этого)? Дано предложение, задан конкретный вопрос. Или тогда нужно всех просить давать предложение в окружении других, как это сделано в сегодняшнем вопросе Kirill'a о союзе "как".

Comment: Александр, это ваше право рассматривать тот конкретный вариант, который был задан. Но вы и его объясняете, как мне кажется, недостаточно полно и ясно. Надо бы рассмотреть варианты  с тире и без него, сравнить их, рассказать как слово «само» влияет на выбор. Это прилагательное? Тогда рассматриваем предложение  «Испанец воплощенное  совершенство». Там есть варианты?  И т.д.

Comment: Что мне понравилось в комментарии? Там сказано: «Можно поставить, если хотите кого-то охарактеризовать, выразить своё впечатление». Это семантика, но она помогает правильно расставить ударения, логически выделив слово «испанец». А если мы переходим к сложному предложению, то этой семантики нет: ударения там другие, задачи другие. Общее помогает нам лучше понять частное. Что-то в этом роде.

Comment: @Sharon Зачем все эти навороты (сложные предложения)?  *"Испанец – воплощенное совершенство"*. Вариантов нет, так же как и в *"Испанец – совершенство"*. Прилагательное не должно влиять. Если же варианты есть, то тогда мы просто отходим от правил или вольно их трактуем, опираясь только на интонацию. А вот слово "сам" не совсем прилагательное, оно, как пишут, местоименное прилагательное и, уже на мой взгляд, близко в этом случае к тем словам, когда тире можно не ставить. Мой ответ предельно ясный: есть пауза между подлежащим и сказуемым – ставим, нет – нет.

Comment: Мое мнение тоже предельно ясно.  Есть варианты? Тогда проводим интонационно-структурный анализ, выясняем синтаксические оттенки. (Пауза, кстати,  относится к интонации.) Пауза, она не есть или нет, мы ее сами ставим для выражения разной семантики, а не просто так. Но, конечно, пугать пользователей таким словами не надо, а нужно все сказанное перевести на общечеловеческой язык. Но я уважаю ваше мнение и доказывать что-то свое не буду.

Comment: @Sharon Мы ходим по одному и тому же месту :)). Хочет автор интонационно (паузно) в силу семантики выделить – ставит, не нужно ему это – не ставит. На этом здесь я усё.

Comment: Я тоже усё, просто отвечала на ваш комментарий. Вы больше вне критики, а испанец – само очарование. На этом и закончим))  Кстати, любители простых решений уже за вас голосуют))  Вы бы, наверное, понравились избирателям, если бы занимались политикой.

Comment: @Sharon Не могу удержаться. )  А какое может быть сложное решение? Только третье. Потому что два уже обсудили. // Чур-чур (это на счёт политики).

Comment: Я еще не придумала)) А разве я говорила о третьем? Мне ваше первое не особо понравилось, когда вы говорили про слово "само", про сущ. в И.п. и т.д.  А еще про желание тоже. Доказательство должно быть убедительным, а я вот ввм не поверила)

Comment: А Татьяна молчит... Скажите, пожалуйста, какое решение вы приняли.

Comment: Александр, @Sharon, Спасибо вам за дискуссию. К сожалению, не смогла сразу сюда зайти. Поняла всё, о чём вы говорили. Чувствую, что не хватает контекста. 
А если будет такое продолжение:
"Испанец само очарование – весёлый, галантный, эрудированный". Видимо, вторая часть - приложение. Тогда двойное тире не очень хорошо будет смотреться. 
Простите, что не дала контекст сразу.

Comment: Татьяна, такой вариант годится, тем более если об испанце мы уже что-то знаем. Ударение будет падать на "очарование". Если же, например, идёт перечисление, то можно так: "Француз – такой-то. Итальянец – такой-то. Испанец – само очарование: весёлый, галантный, эрудированный". Параллельные конструкции с выделением героев, а после двоеточия раскрываем содержание очарования. :))

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за такую иллюстрацию. Теперь всё понятно! ))

Comment: В любом случае постановка тире не будет ошибкой. Это самое общее правило между подлежащим и сказуемым. Хотите обозначить паузу – ставьте не думая. И поощрять участников не забывайте :))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

При подчёркнутой паузе тире будет самое то, тем более что подлежащее и сказуемое выражены существительными. Сомнение, думаю, возникает из-за слова «само».

> **1. САМ** <...> **3.** ***только ед.*** Воплощённый, олицетворённый. *Ты само совершенство. Хозяйка-то сама простота. Его слог – само изящество. Ваш протест – сама правда.*

Большой толковый словарь ([Грамота.ру](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic?word=%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC&all=x))

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ** (после всех комментариев)

В справочниках сказано о том, что между подлежащим и сказуемым при отсутствии связки ставится тире, если они выражены существительными.
**Обычно** (!) тире не ставится, если в роли связки выступают сравнительные союзы, если перед сказуемым есть отрицание ***не***, если между главными членами стоит вводное слово, наречие, частица (всё это тоже связывает). И слово «само», как мне видится, является своеобразной связкой. Также тире не ставится в некоторых других случаях, в том числе в простых по составу предложениях разговорного стиля (см. [Справочник Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=91)).

Если ответ показался неполным, конкретизирую: **возможны оба варианта** (что и подтверждается примерами из словаря).

*Исп**А**нец – само соверш**Е**нство.

Испанец само соверш**Е**нство.*

Выбор зависит от контекста (что мы уже знаем, например, об этом испанце). Если автор хочет интонационно выделить подлежащее, он ставит тире (при этом будет два ударения и характерная пауза). Если основное ударение падает на сказуемое, тире нет.

О паузе, об интонационном подчёркивании и о связанной с этим постановке тире написано во многих правилах, относящихся к разным темам. Мы можем везде поставить тире между главными членами предложения даже при наличии всех тех слов, когда **обычно** оно не ставится.

Comment: А если не подчеркивать паузу? Ведь оба варианта возможны. И кажется мне, что причина какая-то другая, да и слово "само" к обоим вариантам подходит.

Comment: @Sharon Ну да, это логично вытекает из моего утверждения. И смотрим примеры в словаре. Здесь  слово «само» вклинивается между подл. и сказ. наподобие частиц, наречий, вводных слов, когда можно не ставить тире.

Comment: Если слово "само" не влиет на знак, то что же влияет? Вот это мне пока непонятно. Как пользователь языка должен сделать выбор, когда пауза уместна, а когда нет. Мне кажется, что это нужно обозначить. Иначе создается впечатление, что пауза делается по непонятному внутреннему ощущению автора. По интуиции, что ли... Вопрос, к сожалению, принципиальный, ведь так многие думают...

Comment: Интересно, что наш участник в первом комментарии указывал возможную семантику вариантов... Вот это мне понравилось. Всё имеет свою причину.

Comment: @Sharon А мне кажется, что вопрос элементарный. Ведь во всех правилах пишут: есть пауза – ставим; нет – не ставим. Хотите интонационно выделить – ставьте.

Comment: Элементарный?  Хорошо, спасибо за ваше мнение. Где-то я недавно слышала это слово, правда, в форме "элементарнейший". Главное – другой причины искать не надо, это всего лишь наше желание. Подкупающая простота при решении проблемы, она многим понравится. Еще раз спасибо.

Comment: @Sharon Ладно, не элементарный, а не очень сложный. Ну так семантика определяет интонацию, отсюда и пляшем. Что ещё здесь придумывать?

Comment: Спасибо, я вас услышала.  О семантике вы не говорите, семантика была в первом комментарии по теме.   Ну да ладно, закроем вопрос. Главное для меня  – ваше мнение, не в словах дело. Много сегодня впечатлений...

Comment: @Sharon А зачем говорить о семантике? (Можно не отвечать.) Вы здесь о ней упомянули в связи с комментарием под вопросом, вот я и ответил здесь же, как оно складывпется в моей голове.

Comment: Александр, голосую за ваш ответ, совсем чуть-чуть в нем не хватает того, чего хотелось бы мне. Но сейчас уже не тот момент, чтобы дальше что-то дополнять.

Comment: @Sharon, грация вэри шён!

Answer (score -1):

Затруднения с этой темой связаны с некачественным её описанием в справочнике Розенталя.

Как следовало бы сделать. Нужно было ввести термин ‟есть-тире” (тире на месте пропущенноё связки), потом отдельно описать то, когда оно ставится (всегда, кроме тех ситуаций, когда сказуемое – прилагательное, когда подлежащее – личное местоимение и т. д.). Мы бы отчётливо увидели, о какой паузе идёт речь по примерам, когда она есть и когда её нет, мы бы отчётливо знали, когда ставится есть-тире, а когда оно не ставится. Мы бы видели, что речь идёт о паузе, которая есть в одном предложении и которой нет в другом, как в предложениях: ‟Москва – столица России” и ‟Степан нам сосед”. Или если это не пауза, а просто условность ставить есть-тире в такой ситуации, мы бы тоже это знали. А после этого правила сказать, что хоть на месте пропущенной связки ‟есть” может и не быть есть-тире, но может быть любое другое тире, например, тире выразительной паузы. В предложении: ‟Он – герой!” – не ставится есть-тире (есть пункт правила, который гласит, что если подлежащее – личное местоимение, то есть-тире не ставится), но ставится другое тире – тире выразительной паузы. Розенталь просто смешал всё в кучу, у него просто там бардак, у него смешаны есть-тире и все остальные тире. Нужно было отдельно описать про есть-тире. Из-за смешивания причин ставить или не ставить тире никто не знает, о какой паузе идёт речь.

Я рекомендую просто в такой ситуации использовать тот **принцип отсутствия отчётливых предписаний**, предложенный одним пользователем. Он заключается в следующем: Если мы не имеем каких-то отчётливых инструкций по каким-то синтаксическим ситуациям, то мы можем просто написать их сами, но так, чтобы они не противоречили отчётливым официальным пунктам, в таком случае никто не сможет сказать, что мы ошиблись, если мы будем писать по таким правилам. Люди просто хотят комфортно пользоваться пунктуацией, никому не нужны какие-то неопределённости, сложности, колебания и т. д, пунктуация не должна быть сложнее пальца. Вот так должно было выглядеть правило:

**0. Есть-тире на месте пропущенной связки ‟есть” ставится всегда, кроме следующих пунктов:**

**1. Сказуемое – сравнительный оборот.**

> Облака словно сказочные чудовища.
> Сегодня небо точно море.

**2. Между подлежащим и сказуемым обособляемое сочетание, как вводное, причастный оборот, придаточное предложение и т. д.**

> Дубава, кажется, друг Корчагина.
> Риск, как известно, дело благородное.

(В справочнике Розенталя только про вводные написано, но я добавляю всё остальное для последовательности.)

**3. Между подлежащим и сказуемым стоит дополнение в дательном падеже, как в предложениях в примерах этого пункта.**

> Степан нам сосед.
> Коля мне друг.

И так далее, я уже не буду описывать все пункты. Но **ответ** на вопрос в том, что здесь есть-тире по пункту 0. В итоге: Испанец – само очарование.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146683/discussion-on-answer-by-rumpelstiltskin-----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.